# AJAX: Auto select with combo-box

Tags: jquery

I am populating list in combo-box like

[image]

and this is the function which I call on **onkeyup** in textbox:

```
function findword(id, comptext){

        if(comptext.value != ''){
            for (i=0;i<id.options.length;i++){
                id.options[i].selected = false;
            }

            var sc=comptext.value;
            var r, re;
            re = /\(/i;
            r = sc.replace(re, "\\(");
            sc=r;
            re = /\)/i;
            r = sc.replace(re, "\\)");
            sc=r;
            re = /\./i;
            r = sc.replace(re, "\\.");
            sc=r;
            re = /\+/i;
            r = sc.replace(re, "\\+");
            sc=r;
            re = /\?/i;
            r = sc.replace(re, "\\?");
            sc=r;
            var cmplength=sc.length;
            var rex=RegExp(sc, "gi");
            for (i=0;i<id.options.length;i++){
                var sts=id.options[i].text.substring(0,cmplength);
                var result=sts.search(rex);
                if(result>-1){
                    id.options[i].selected = true;
                }
            }
        }else{
            for (i=0;i<id.options.length;i++){
                id.options[i].selected = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

with this function I can select all values which starts with specified input in the **text-box** let say if I type **api** it select all values started with **api** but if I type **color** it does nothing.

Now please review the above function & point out what more checks I have to add & where should I add these checks?

Comment: I wouldn't say this was a solution to your problem but an alternative method maybe to use the Select2 jQuery library - http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just fixed myself

```
function findword(id, comptext){

        if(comptext.value != ''){
            var srcit = comptext.value;

            for (i=0;i<id.options.length;i++){
                id.options[i].selected = false;
            }

            var patt = new RegExp(srcit, 'i');

            for (i=0;i<id.options.length;i++){

                var result = patt.exec(id.options[i].text);
                if(result != null){
                    id.options[i].selected = true;
                }
            }
        }else{
            for (i=0;i<id.options.length;i++){
                id.options[i].selected = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp